# What happens when a dictionary grows?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, theory

I tried looking around for this, so apologies if it's a duplicate.

We know that under the hood a dictionary is created with a fixed size, and then expands as it fills up. Great.

Say I initialize a dictionary of size 50, and I start putting items in the dictionary. There are some collisions (fine whatever) but at some point the dictionary needs to regrow.

My assumption is, that when this regrow occurs, all items currently in the dictionary would need to have their position recomputed accordingly. Am I correct in my thinking?

Comment: You can usually use [the reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,d3599058f8d79be0) for questions like this. I haven't read the code yet, but it almost certainly contains all the answers you may need about the implementations. As far as I know, internally Dictionary is a [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).

Comment: [Dictionary.Resize()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,443). More or less the same logic applies to `List<T>`, `StringBuilder`, `MemoryStream` etc. Objects that have/allow to specify an initial capacity and use some sort of pre-emptive buffering.

Answer (score 0):

As @someone also suggests, it is better to read reference sources or read the source your self to understand what really happens there. Your assumption may be correct theoretically. But please consider that **what is guaranteed is functionality** and all operations that happen internally may different from a library to another library or even a release to another release of a library duo to optimization, etc.